# Facebook app not asking permissions

Tags: facebook, api

I'm currently working on a Facebook game which users the highscores API, I know it requires some special permissions, which I ask for, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My login url looks like this: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=234234234&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/pages/testPage/2342342342323423?sk=app_448314321899332&state=login&scope=email,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_friendlists,user_hometown,user_location,user_games_activity`

But in the permissions screen it only asks the users for `Post on your behalf` and `Access your custom friend lists`.

Why isn't it asking for the rest of the permissions needed?

I just redirect the user to the login page like this:

```
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=' + window.appId + '&redirect_uri=' + window.canvas + '&state=login&scope=' + window.permissions;
top.window.location = url;
```

EDIT: This also happens when I use the `FB.login()`

```
FB.login(function(response) {
if(response.authResponse) {
    player.app.login();
    } else {
    top.window.location = window.canvas;
    }
}, {scope: window.permissions});
```

`console.log(window.permissions)` returns `email,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_friendlists,user_hometown,user_location,user_games_activity`